# Is it possible to buy all plan parts from Merchant's House?

Tags: paradise-island

I've read that the plans of wonders such as Ruins can be all bought from Merchant's House. However, the last times I visit it, if there is any plan part available, it's the Ruins part 5.

So, did someone get all the needed parts from Merchant's House? Are the parts displayed there really random, or some parts won't show up, so that the user will be forced to use piasters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. The two ways to get the plan parts are to

- Purchase them from the merchant house for shells, pearls and rings;
- Donate to the idol (Although it may not be what you need)

Read up about the ruins here: 
[The Ruins](http://paradiseislandhd.wikia.com/wiki/Ruins)

Read up about how the merchant house works (Restocking, etc) here: 
[Merchant House](http://paradiseislandhd.wikia.com/wiki/Merchant%27s_house)